# How do I get the tilt and direction of the tilt from an aruco marker using opencv in python?

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

I am trying to find the angle of tilt from an aruco code, I am fairly new to using aruco codes so I do not know where to begin trying to figure this out. I just need to take the information (angle, and direction(respective to the screen)) and print it to a .txt file.

I included the code that I have written so far. I do not know if that will be helpful at all, I just put it there in case it is of any use.

Here is my code so far:

```
import time
import cv2
import cv2.aruco as aruco
import math

passedA = False
passedB = False
angleA = 0
angleB = 0
tsB = 0
tsA = 0
speed = 0
timeDist = 0

disCalc = 1


def getAngle(a, b, c):
    ang = math.degrees(math.atan2(c[1] - b[1], c[0] - b[0]) - math.atan2(a[1] - b[1], a[0] - b[0]))
    return ang + 360 if ang < 0 else ang


def findArucoMarkers(img, markerSize=6, totalMarkers=250, draw=True):
    imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    key = getattr(aruco, f'DICT_{markerSize}X{markerSize}_{totalMarkers}')
    arucoDict = aruco.Dictionary_get(key)
    arucoParam = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
    bbox, ids, rejected = aruco.detectMarkers(imgGray, arucoDict, parameters=arucoParam)

    if draw:
        aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(img, bbox)

    return [bbox, ids]


def augmentAruco(bbox, id, img, imgAug, drawID=True):
    tl = bbox[0][0][0], bbox[0][0][1]
    tr = bbox[0][1][0], bbox[0][1][1]
    br = bbox[0][2][0], bbox[0][2][1]
    bl = bbox[0][3][0], bbox[0][3][1]

    textPos = int(bbox[0][0][0]) - int(30), int(bbox[0][0][1]) + int(30)

    centerW = float(bbox[0][2][0] - bbox[0][0][0]) / float(2) + float(bbox[0][0][0])
    centerH = float(bbox[0][2][1] - bbox[0][0][1]) / float(2) + float(bbox[0][0][1])
    center = int(centerW), int(centerH)

    angleFactor = int(centerW), int(centerH) + int(-100)

    # print(bbox)
    # print(centerW)
    # print(centerH)
    # print(center)
    # print(angleA)
    # print(angleB)

    # h, w, c = imgAug.shape
    # pts1 = np.array([tl, tr, br, bl])

    if id == 0:
        if 150 < int(centerW) < 170:
            global angleA
            angleA = getAngle(tr, center, angleFactor)
            global tsA
            tsA = time.time()
            print("Pos A angle = " + str(angleA) + " DEGREES")
            print("Pos A timestamp = " + str(tsA) + " SECONDS")
            global passedA
            passedA = True
    # print(passedA)
    if id == 0:
        if 400 < int(centerW) < 420:
            global angleB
            angleB = getAngle(tr, center, angleFactor)
            global tsB
            tsB = time.time()
            print("Pos B angle = " + str(angleB) + " DEGREES")
            print("Pos B timestamp = " + str(tsB) + " SECONDS")
            global passedB
            passedB = True
    # print(passedB)
    if passedA and passedB:
        if id == 0:
            if 480 < int(centerW) < 520:
                angleChange = float(angleA) - float(angleB)
                global timeDist
                timeDist = float(tsB) - float(tsA)
                global speed
                speed = float(disCalc) / float(timeDist)
                angleChangePerS = float(angleChange) / float(timeDist)

                if angleB > angleA:
                    angleChange = float(angleA) + float(360) - (float(angleB))
                    angleChangePerS = float(angleChange) / float(timeDist)
                    print(speed)
                    print("the angle changed by " + str(angleChangePerS) + " degrees per second")
                    print("The speed of the disc is " + str(speed) + " feet per per second")

                    f = open("Resources/DiscReadings.txt", "w")
                    f.write("%s \n %s \n %s \n" % (str(speed), str(angleChangePerS), 0))
                    f.writelines([str(speed), str(angleChangePerS)])
                    f.close()

                else:
                    print("the angle changed by " + str(angleChangePerS) + " degrees per second")
                    print("The speed of the disc is " + str(speed) + " feet per per second")

                    f = open("Resources/DiscReadings.txt", "w")
                    f.write("%s \n %s \n %s \n" % (1, str(speed), str(angleChangePerS)))
                    f.close()


    if drawID:
        cv2.putText(img, str(id), textPos, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, .7, (255, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str("."), center, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, .7, (255, 10, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str("."), tr, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, .7, (255, 10, 0), 2)

        cv2.line(img, center, tr, (255, 10, 0), 3)
        cv2.line(img, center, angleFactor, (255, 10, 0), 3)

        # cv2.line(img, (0, 0), (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]), (0, 255, 0), 3)

        return img


def main():


    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    imgAug = cv2.imread("Resources/target.png")

    while True:
        success, image = cap.read()
        arucoFound = findArucoMarkers(image)
        if len(arucoFound[0]) != 0:
            for bbox, id in zip(arucoFound[0], arucoFound[1]):
                image = augmentAruco(bbox, id, image, imgAug)

        cv2.imshow("Image", image)
        cv2.waitKey(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The opencv Aruco tags tutorial has a solid example of using solvePNP with Aruco tags: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html